# SQL Exclude row based on other rows value

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, window-functions

```
LINE_INVOICE    PAYMENT_SOURCE    SOURCE_PMT_ID                     
-1              Payment Received    7369442                                         
1               Payment Received    7369442                                         
2               Payment Received    7369442                                         
3               Payment Received    7369442                                         
4               Payment Received    7369442                                         
5               Payment Received    7369442                                         
6               Payment Received    7369442                                         
7               Payment Received    7369442                                         
8               Payment Received    7369442                                         
9               Payment Received    7369442                                         
10              Payment Received    7369442                                         
11              Payment Received    7369442                                         
12              Payment Received    7369442
```

I would like to remove the '-1' row anytime there is in any other number in the 'Line invoice column'. This is specfic for each Source_PMT_ID. If there is no '1' row return -1.  How can I capture this in my sql query?

Comment: In your sample data, you would like the row with -1 in the LINE_INVOICE to be removed, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that you want window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        max(case when line_invoice <> -1 then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by source_pmt_id) flag
    from mytable t
) t
where line_invoice <> -1 or flag = 0
```

The window `max()` in the subquery checks if at least one row exists with the same `source_pmt_id` and a `line_invoice` value other than `-1`. The outer query uses that information to filter out rows where `line_invoice` has value `-1`, while retaining those that have no other value for the same `source_pmt_id`.

Comment: This is needed for Oracle SQL

Comment: I tried this solution in Fiddle and it returns the -1 for the data set given. I think what the OP is asking for is that the -1 be removed in this case.

Comment: @LarsSkaug: my bad, the last condition had to be `flag = 0`. Fixed.

Comment: This solution also works once "line" is replaced by "line_invoice" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming -1 is the lowest number and that line_invoice goes up from there:

```
select * 
from table1 tab
where LINE_INVOICE >= case when (select max(line_invoice) 
                                from table1 tb_
                                where tb_.payment_source = tab.payment_source
                                 and tb_.source_pmt_id = tab.source_pmt_id) = -1 then -1 else 0 end
```

[This Fiddle shows how it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8815fb/1).

Answer (score 0):

One way with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(line_invoice) over (partition by SOURCE_PMT_ID) as max_line_invoice
      from t
     ) t
where line_invoice > -1 or max_line_invoice = -1;
```

Or, without a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by source_pmt_id
                            order by case when line_invoice <> -1 then 1 else 2 end
                           )
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```